# Trying to 'submit' my form when hitting enter fails

Tags: jquery, forms, form-submit

I have a form with a hidden submit button.

When I try to submit the form using the enter key it fails (alert doesn't display).

I use the following JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('div.quick-login form').submit(function() {
        alert('test');

        return false;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MsFY6/

Any ideas as to why my code doesn't work?

**UPDATE**

Browser I tested it with is Chrome.

Comment: Works for me in FireFox 8.0 and IE 8.  Are you sure this is the issue?

Comment: and works in safari latest version and ie6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I always do is put in a .keypress() handler which checks the keycode.

```
$("#inputbox").keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 13) {
    alert('test');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Works for me in FireFox 8.0 and IE 8.  What browser are you using?  They do have this disclaimer in the documentation for [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/):

> Depending on the browser, the Enter key may only cause a form
>   submission if the form has exactly one text field, or only when there
>   is a submit button present. The interface should not rely on a
>   particular behavior for this key unless the issue is forced by
>   observing the keypress event for presses of the Enter key.

Sounds like you shouldn't be counting on the Enter key.

Answer (score 1):

I *can* reproduce the error in Safari/Chrome. The reason is because the submit button is `display: none;`-ed. [If you unhide it, it works](http://jsfiddle.net/MsFY6/3/), you can also do `visibilty: hidden;` [and have it work](http://jsfiddle.net/MsFY6/4/).

An option may be to [bind to a keypress as well](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) - the return key, `keyCode` is 13.

Comment: Damn Webkit! Or is it all other browser who's doing it wrong? Will try to find out what the spec says.

Comment: Cannot find anything in spec. :(

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your example:

With keycode: http://jsfiddle.net/MsFY6/7/

With visibilty hidden: http://jsfiddle.net/MsFY6/8/

Comment: Thanks. But keep in mind that there is no need to add `id`s to the input fields. Just `$('.quick-login input').keypress()` is better to use. Especially when using generic names like `password` and `username`.